# Websphere all logs are going to SystemOut.log

Tags: java, log4j, websphere

I am using Log4j in my application and have some appenders for debug and error. I tested this on tomcat and working fine. Generating all logs in their respective files. But when I deploy code on WAS6.1 all logs are getting generated only inside SystemOut.log.

Please help!

Comment: It will be good if you attach some code. I am using websphere and getting all my logs in separate log file.

Comment: Are you using any logging facade such as commons-logging? If so, you should change classloading order to parent-last.

Comment: You don't have to do parent-last, and as it has other effects, I'd avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem might be that WebSphere 6.1 uses Jakarta Commons Logging (JCL) internally, and if any of your code or 3rd-party libraries also use JCL, WebSphere's configuration conflicts with your application trying to use log4j. If this is happening, you'll see exactly what you're seeing.

There are multiple [references](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/ctrb_classload_jcl_conf.html) and [blog posts](http://majikshoe.blogspot.com/2009/01/joys-of-websphere-61-and-commons.html) that describe ways to address this. We've found the simplest to be creating a file named `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` in the `META-INF/services` directory of your web application (in the root of the WAR archive). This file must contain the line:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jFactory
```

(At least with newer versions of WebSphere...) Another key is that the JCL jar must be loaded from the same location as the log4j jar. e.g. either both from WEB-INF/lib or both from a shared library. Thus, you can't fall back on loading JCL from WebSphere's own provided copy. If they're loaded by [different classloaders](http://websphereapplicationservernotes.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/classnotfound-a-close-look-at-class-loader-in-websphere-application-server/), they can't properly see each other.