# log4j generating logger file but not appending anything

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, documentum

The settings I have specified in log4j is as follows:

```
log4j.appender.F2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.F2.File=E\:/Documentum/logs/dflogger.log
log4j.appender.F2.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.F2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.F2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p [%t] %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.myorg.mytbo.tbo=DEBUG,F2
```

I am trying to log information from inside TBO (defined in package `com.myorg.mytbo.tbo`) which is essentially a JAR deployed on jboss application server inside EMC Documentum Content Server. This specific information about Documentum server shouldn't be any concern since it still uses `org.apache.log4j`. When the TBO runs it creates `dflogger.log` but does not append any information inside it.

I suspect many reasons like:

- File is getting created in readonly mode.
- or may be there is some issue associated with logging for `com.myorg.mytbo.tbo`, for which [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268120/log4j-does-not-log-anything) is somewhat similar thread, specifying `PARENT_FIRST` option in websphere. But I am using jboss, so if the issue is similar then can anyone tell if I need to modify jboss settings?