# After Fixpack 45 for websphere 6.1 log4j creates file but not populate it

Tags: log4j, websphere-6.1

I have a strange problem with my component that is a TrustAssociationInterceptor and it starts up with the Application Server, so it's not deployed.
After the upgrade to version 45 of my websphere 6.1 my log4j does not log into the file I've specified in the properties of my custom component but only into the SystemOut.log .
I can change the logging level only by the WebSphere console. 
It seems websphere has the control of log4j.  The log file of the custom component is created but not populated.

Has anyone any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely seen this behavior in WAS 6.1 before due to JCL, but I can't think of any reason it would start just with a new Fixpack. What fixpack were you on before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131529/websphere-all-logs-are-going-to-systemout-log/8138477#8138477

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I previously have installed the version 6.1.0.31

Comment: I done the rollback to the v.31 some days ago and the file has been created and populated without any problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have you deployed 6.1.0-WS-WASSDK-WinX32-FP0000045.pak along with 6.1.0-WS-WAS-WinX32-FP0000045.pak, Is that to do something with SDK ?