# Framework internal logs going to system.out (websphere 7.0)

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, websphere

I'm using `Log4j` in my application and application logging is working fine while framework in my application is internally using `commons-logging` and logs are going to `System.out` but I want to redirect them to a separate file and also want to enable `DEBUG` level.

Tested this on tomcat and working fine. Generating all logs in their respective files. But when I deploy code on WAS7.0, only `INFO` level of framework logs are being generated SystemOut.log. (my `log4j.xml` is fine as it is working fine on tomcat)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131529/websphere-all-logs-are-going-to-systemout-log/ ?

Comment: @dbreaux already tried it. not working!

Comment: Is slf4j in use by any chance?

Comment: I also tried to use `slf4j` but it didn't work out...

Comment: I'm just saying that if any of the libs use slf4j, you might also need the jcl-over-slf4j.jar to get those log items also out of SystemOut. http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: Yes I've already tried using jcl-over-slf4j and slf4j-log4j12, logs did move out from the `System.out` but `log4j.xml` was somehow not being read. Can there be any conflict between frameworks logging API and `log4j` as framework is using `Logback`?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I found the answer in Websphere Docs.

> Note: Trace information, which includes events at the Fine, Finer and
>   Finest levels, can be written only to the trace log. Therefore, if you
>   do not enable diagnostic trace, setting the log detail level to Fine,
>   Finer, or Finest does not effect the logged data.

Reference: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Frtrb_loglevels.html

In Java Utility Logging terms FINE = DEBUG, so DEBUG level and below will not appear in System.out, only int the WAS trace log.