# Logging framewok for Websphere Application Server 7

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1, websphere-8

I have tried several logging frameworks (log4j / slf4j with logback/ commons-logging)  on websphere to redirect each application log on a separate file, without any sucess.

If i have two applications deployed on same JVM: I am not able to know related errors of each application: All non catched exceptions gets redirected to SystemOut.log file, instead of getting redirected to the appropriate application log file.

Is there any way to achieve that on websphere ?

Comment: See http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131529/websphere-all-logs-are-going-to-systemout-log/ ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you post the configuration files you've tried for each logging framework, and provide more details of each scenario. I have used log4j and logback with WebSphere and never ran into problems like yours.