# MyBatis Logging in Websphere Shared Library

Tags: logging, log4j, mybatis, websphere-portal

How can I get mybatis to log the sql statements when it is being used in a shared jar?  The applications that use that shared app are using log4j so I've tried calling `org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory.useLog4JLogging()`, but that didn't help.

I've also tried setting the websphere log detail levels to "all" for the different mybatis classes and java.sql classes, but that didn't help either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Portal and what version of WAS is it running on?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the JDK logging API in Portal before (and it's what I would recommend to use for new development). But I think setting up Log4J in a portlet/shared lib on Portal would be the same to setting it up for any WAS application. Nothing should have to be special about Portal compared to just WAS.

With that said though, I've got a few links you could try looking at to help get you on the right path for using Log4J.

http://www.alexander-bown.com/2009/08/using-commons-logging-1-1-with-log4j-on-websphere-6-0/

[log4j not working in WebSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276305/log4j-not-working-in-websphere)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14045904

Comment: I have various portlet apps that use Log4J without issue.  This particular situation is related to a jar that is in a shared library.  This jar uses the mybatis framework to connect to various DS on websphere and I'm trying to log the sql statements that mybatis executes.  Some of my portlet apps do this without issues, but that is not that case in the jar.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Ok, I did not understand your problem initially. My next thoughts then are to see if you can use Log4J in your portlet that is using your shared library. Then I'm also curious if your shared library is on the server classpath or application classpath (though I don't know if that would affect anything but just curious).

Comment: Yes the portlet app using the shared library has log4J configured and logs correctly.  The shared library is on the server classpath.

Comment: Hmm, I probably don't know enough about log4J but my brain won't let this question go. Since the shared lib is on the server classpath, perhaps the log4j config it's using is loaded on server startup and even though your app says this is the new config your shared lib has already load and has its config. Could you try putting the jar into the application classpath instead of the server classpath?

Comment: I've also tried that and the code in the jar does log out to the same log as the portlet app, but the mybatis still doesn't.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Sorry I couldn't help more. Please let me know what the problem and solution ended up being when you figure it out. Good luck.